# Failed to submit instant app on play store - Base APK error

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap, intel-xdk, android-instant-apps

I was trying to submit an apk of mine to the play store instant app section when i get the error - **Your Instant App APKs should contain at least one base APK.**

Now, the app was compiled using phonegap and phonegap provides only one APK which I have submitted to the play store. 
I have read several documentations and other similar Qs but I can't find a solution to this.

The APK i am trying to submit as an Instant App is well under the 4mb limit and is properly signed too.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT : Tried submitting a zip too, no success. Is there anything specific the apk should be called or is instantApp fine?

Answer (score 2):

The upload for an instant app should be a "Bundle" which Android Studio will create for you, it isn't just a single APK.

If you are trying to create using phonegap, it *might* work if you create a Zip file which contains your APK (not just renaming your APK to a zip).

So upload "instant.zip" which contains your apk "instant.apk"

It is also looking for the APK who's gradle contains `baseFeature true`, that is the base APK. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html)

Comment: Thanks, just tried this but no success.
Still shows the error -
**Upload failed
Your Instant App APKs should contain at least one base APK.**

Comment: It is looking for the APK who's gradle contains `baseFeature true`, that is the base APK. (and yes, the instant app APK(s) should be inside a zip file) https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html

Answer (score 0):

As TWL said, you might not have declared your module as base module. Here is how my `build.gradle` for base module looks like.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro', getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }

    baseFeature true
}
```

You have to do two things.

1. apply `com.android.feature` plugin
2. set `baseFeature` true inside android block

Comment: Really appreciate you writing all that down, but as i've mentioned I compile using phonegap, meaning all my code is in HTML, CSS, JS and other web libraries. I'm not quite sure I can incorporate the above into my app directly, even in the config.xml file

Comment: You may have to reach out to Phonegap and see if they support Instant App development then.